# Liquibase Error

Tags: database, maven, liquibase

I am trying to setup a maven based liquibase database setup, but getting the following error when I run something from the build/target directory. Following is the debug information and directory structure for the change logs.

```
/com/example/database/.),liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineResourceAccessor(file:/home/www-data/workspace/database/src/main/resource/com/example/database/lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar))
DEBUG 4/28/15 11:48 PM: liquibase: Release Database Lock
DEBUG 4/28/15 11:48 PM: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE LB_TEST.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 0, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1
INFO 4/28/15 11:48 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock

INFO 4/28/15 11:48 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException

SEVERE 4/28/15 11:48 PM: liquibase: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:27)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:215)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1073)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:178)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:97)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:260)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:221)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:27)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.include(DatabaseChangeLog.java:377)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:258)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.exception.SetupException
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:260)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:221)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:27)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.include(DatabaseChangeLog.java:377)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:258)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:355)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:274)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:221)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:343)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineResourceAccessor.list(CommandLineResourceAccessor.java:39)
    at liquibase.resource.CompositeResourceAccessor.list(CompositeResourceAccessor.java:40)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:332)
    ... 16 more
```

Any idea what is it ?

Directory Structure:

```
.
|-- changelog
|   |-- changelog-1.0.0.xml
|   |-- changelog-install.xml
|   `-- v000
|       |-- cst
|       |   |-- entity_extra_data.xml
|       |   |-- entity.xml
|       |   |-- group_mapping.xml
|       |-- master.xml
|       |-- seq
|       `-- tab
|           |-- company.xml
|           |-- entity_extra_data.xml
|           |-- entity.xml
|           `-- group_mapping.xml
|-- db_install
|-- lib
|   |-- ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar
`-- liquibase.properties
```

Comment: Can you include the command line you used? It isn't clear what you mean when you say "when I try to run something from the build/target directory"

It would also be helpful to see what your changelog files look like.

Comment: liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog/changelog-install.xml update;

Comment: Ooops, don't how come! But its working at the moment. I really didn't make any changes to the above directory structure or any scripts or xml :(.

Comment: The error would suggest there was something wrong in your changeLog.xml

Answer (score 0):

Another easier way to run your liquibase directly from maven project is to use the liquibase maven plugin

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<project>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
          <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
            <propertyFile>target/classes/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
```

and from project root folder you just run
mvn liquibase:update
to update the database (note the liquibase.properties file, in resources)